# How to attach public IP to EKS pod

Tags: ip, amazon-eks, whitelist

I'm working on a project which is running on EKS/AWS.
We have a node in the system which need to communicate with an external system with a IP white-list.

I found out that the nodes have a public IP but this isn't working because that would mean I need to add all the nodes to the whitelist..

My question is; how can I set a public IP to a specific pod in my K8s deployment?

Comment: Can you please +1 this (as you see appropriate)? https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1319

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup NAT with Elastic IP address and route your cluster egress thru this NAT. This way you only need to whitelist the NAT public IP. On top of that, you can opt to place all your worker nodes in the private subnet for better security. See [Public+Private subnets](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/de-mystifying-cluster-networking-for-amazon-eks-worker-nodes/) for more details.

Comment: This is your guy sven!

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with the help of your answer and this article https://blog.tooljet.com/aws-nat-eks/. The EKS was already configured with a NAT and an elastic IP in my case. I only needed to add a route rule to route traffic with a certain destination through the NAT. Thanks!